# How can I get something like Dwarf Therapist running on a Mac?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I'm quickly losing track of my dwarven brothers because there are so many of them and their names have nothing to do with their jobs.

I want to use something like Dwarf Therapist on my mac, but the latest version that Mac Manager supports is like 0.28 and I'm playing the latest version.

Wine doesn't open Dwarf Therapist, so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to get it or something similar working on a mac short of running a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone is currently porting Dwarf Therapist to OS X. Right now it works, but has lots of bugs, and is a little hard to install if you aren't familiar with working on the command line. It is separate from the official Dwarf Therapist, but when more bugs get worked out, it will be merged. If you can get it to work, it will be much better than running through wine. If not, check back in a couple of months for a more stable version.

http://code.google.com/r/jofarrell-dwarftherapistosx/

Comment: Where do you get the idea that it will be merged when it works? Apart from the fact DT has no official maintainer, there's nothing linking them together.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/dwarffortress/comments/cpatb/dwarf_therapist_sorry_therapist_on_osx/

The top voted comment is by chmod700, who is one of the developers of dwarf therapist, saying he will incorporate the os x version into the main project. There also is discussion about this side project on the google code page for the actual dwarf fortress.

Comment: In the last sentence, I meant there is discussion about it on the actual dwarf *therapist* code page. See the (Port to Mac) items: http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist/updates/list

Comment: I don't know what all the functions of Dwarf Therapist are, never having used it, but the mac port successfully sets occupations, which is more than enough to get me going.  And yes, it works very well.

Answer (score 2):

The mac bundle "Dwarf Builder" contains a copy of Dwarf Therapist that seems to work great. http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=106974.0